# Matplotlib, synchronize time axis between scatter-, violin- and boxplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

In order to combine various informations with synchronised x-axis (a time axis, `numpy.datetime64`) I have written the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_axis = [np.datetime64("2016-01-01"), np.datetime64("2016-02-01")]
y_data = [3, 5]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312, sharex=ax1)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313, sharex=ax1)

# Plot the scatter plot    
ax1.scatter(x_axis, y_data)

# Now draw the violinplot and the boxplot
for (timestamp, y) in zip(x_axis, y_data):
    data = np.random.rand(100) + y
    ax2.violinplot(data,
                   positions=[timestamp],
                   widths=[np.timedelta64(500000, 's')])
#    ax3.boxplot(data,
#                positions=[timestamp],
#                widths=[np.timedelta64(10, 's')])
```

The problem now is the third (commented) part: when defining the positions and withs in correct units everything works fine, so a scatterplot can be plotted on a time axis, but the boxplot fails when plotting the whiskers. I receive a `TypeError: ufunc multiply cannot use operands with types dtype('float64') and dtype('<M8[D]')`.

Is there any way to properly draw a boxplot on a real time axis, so that synchronisation works as required?

PS: Note, the widths are in units seconds, if the time unit is too large, the violinplot is not smooth any more...

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [seaborn](http://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/elaborate_violinplot.html) for this. There are multiple options for `violinplot()` to include a boxplot etc.

Comment: I tried to use seaborn, but getting the time axis working correctly is again not really working as expected, especially when trying to synchronize an axis with other matplotlib figures.